# JQuery handles event, but does not execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a div with class="evidence" that holds 4 elements (buttons) that I would like to manage via jQuery. I have to change the background color of the button clicked, and reset the other 3 button backgrounds to simulate toggle button

I wrote this:

```
$('.evidence [id^=button]').on('click', function () {
    $('.evidence [id^=button]').not($(this)).css('backgroud-color', '#88e885');
    $(this).css('backgroud-color', '#559153');
});
```

The button IDs start with button, and the buttons are children of the div class="evidence". I can debug with firebug and I can see the breakpoint stop on the $('.evidence [id^=button]') but the function is not executed.

Can you help me?

EDITED

This is my HTML

```
<div class="evidence">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn" ID="button1"/></td>
            <td><asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn" ID="button2"/></td>
            <td><asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn" ID="button3/></td>
            <td><asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn" ID="button4"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This: `.not($(this))` should probably be `.not(this)`.

Comment: Also, `background` is misspelled :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/A9jzR/

```
$('div.evidence button').on('click', function() {
    $('div.evidence button').css('background', '#88e885');
    $(this).css('background', '#559153');
});
```

No need to apply `.not()`. You can color all buttons in toggled color and then just give the desired look to your clicked one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the selector to something after evidence.

`$('.evidence div[id^=button]')`

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have some HTML like:

```
<div class="evidence">
    <button id="button-n1">1<button>
    <button id="button-n2">2<button>
    <button id="button-n3">3<button>
    <button id="button-n4">4<button>
</div>
```

You have a typo in `background-color`, you wrote `backgroud-color` instead, that's because your code is not working.

I suggest to use the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method for what you want to do.

```
$('.evidence [id^=button]').on('click', function () {
   $(this)
     .css('background-color', '#559153')
     .siblings("[id^=button]").css('background-color', '#88e885');
});
```

[Here is a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCGyt/).

Comment: `siblings` will work if only the buttons are siblings. However, we can't see the OP's markup.

Comment: He said: _I have a div with class="evidence" that holds 4 element_, from what i understand, he has a div with four button children. Anyway, i thought like you first so i a added a base markup.

Comment: Better: `jQuery(this).closest('.evidence').find('button')...`; this will work even if the buttons are not siblings.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally recommend pre-selecting the buttons outside the scope of the `click` event, from a slight performance perspective. This is assuming the buttons aren't subject to change.

> I have a div with class="evidence" that holds 4 element (button)

With this in mind, I've used the following selector:

```
var buttons = $('.evidence input[type="button"]');
$(buttons).click(function()
{
    $(buttons).css('background', '#88e885').not(this).css('background', '#559153');
});
```

This also means that you could potentially, and easily, change the selector in a single place without the need for more unnecessary alterations.

You could go a step further a make a jQuery plugin...

```
(function ($)
{
    $.fn.buttonToggler = function (inactiveColour, activeColour)
    {
        var buttons = this;
        return buttons.click(function()
        {
           buttons.css('background', inactiveColour).not(this).css('background', activeColour);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$('.evidence input[type="button"]').buttonToggler('#88e885', '#559153');
​
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="evidence">
    <input type="button" value="1" />
    <input type="button" value="2" />
    <input type="button" value="3" />
    <input type="button" value="4" />
</div>
```

This jQuery works for the above markup:

```
$(".evidence input[type=button]").click(function(){
    $(".evidence input[type=button]").css('background-color', '#559153'),
    $(this).css('background-color', '#88e885');
});
```

This takes a simpler approach than your supplied code sample; when a button is clicked, it resets all of the background colors on the buttons, then sets the color of the clicked button.

Comment: ...Zoltan's post was not here when I started writing this. I need to learn to refresh pages before posting answers. :x

Comment: Your code will not work properly if there are multiple cases of `.evidence` on the page....

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate the event instead, makes more sense. Also, if the buttons are all siblings, use the `.siblings()` function to get the other buttons:

```
$('.evidence').on('click', '[id^=button]', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#559153')
        .siblings().css('background-color', '#88e885');
});
```

If they are not siblings, something like:

```
$('.evidence').on('click', '[id^=button]', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#559153')
        .closest('.evidence').find('[id^=button]')
        .css('background-color', '#88e885');
});
```